# Image not sizing correctly on mobile version of website

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on an eportfolio to showcase some of my projects for scholarships I will be applying to in September. I have the site perfect except for an image that doesn't seem to be sizing correctly when on mobile. Can anyone offer me some assistance? See relevant code and screenshots below:

HTML

```
                <figure class="about-me__img--container">
                    <img src="./assets/undraw_Online_cv_re_gn0a.svg" class="about.me__img" alt="">
                </figure>
```

CSS

```
.about-me__img--container {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 48px;
    animation: fade-in 1200ms 800ms backwards;
}

.about-me__img {
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;  
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Desktop Version
[image]
Mobile version
[image]

Comment: Have you applied any margin to your image or container? because It seems like there is an extra margin-left to the image that is moving it towards the right side.

Comment: Can we have the SVG file? The width and height properties in the SVG need be reduced.

Comment: I think you could try to define the width and height of the image. The mobile phone and desktop may have different pixels.

Comment: @Syed Mohammad Sannan there is only a margin at the top of the image

Comment: @arthur_fleck try defining the width and height of the image manually, and also try margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; to make sure no margin.